# Create empty folder in firebase realtime database with android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my application, when a user registers, he is authenticated and I create it in the realtime database

All of this works perfectly.
The problem is that I need to create an empty folder when creating the user ... And I don't know how to do it

Create the user from the android code:

```
fun dbAddUser(userEmail: String, user: User) {
    database.child(appContext.resources.getString(R.string.word_user))
        .child(userEmail).setValue(user)
}
```

And so it is created in the realtime database:

[image]

I can't concatenate a second "setValue" and in case I could ... How do I indicate the creation of a folder?

I appreciate the help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Realtime Database doesn't have "folders", it has nodes.  And they can't be empty.  Nodes cease to exist if they don't contain any children.  What's your ultimate goal here?

Comment: you're right.  my concept was wrong.  thanks for the clarification.